# Is there a unified cout/wcout to handle char* and wchar*

Tags: visual-c++, visual-c++-2010

I am not sure if there is a unified way to handle char* and wchar* in Visual c++?

Comment: Not AFAIK, though why would you expect to have both mixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reasonably convenient way to handle both `wchar` and `char` strings is via [bstr_t](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k3ebasf%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), which can be constructed from either and cast to either.

Under the covers, this class uses the required Win32 character conversion APIs to ensure correct output.  It's really a COM helper class (`BSTR` is the COM string type), but no reason why you cannot use it even if you don't need COM.